# How to convert list variable name after $ into string

Tags: r

I have the following variable name of list type:

```
tdat$`apoptotic process`
```

What I'd like to do is to extract the term after `$` and then
turn them into a string:

```
"apoptotic process"
```

How can I achieve that?
I tried this but failed:

```
deparse(substitute(tdat$`apoptotic process`))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the `names()` function.  Assuming 'apoptotic process' is the first element in list `tdat`:

```
x <- names(tdat)
x[1]
  `apoptotic process`
```

Comment: I think this depends on the intent... it doesnt work in this case `f <- function(X)  list(names(X), mean(X)); f(mtcars$wt)`

Comment: Of course it won't work in your example since you are calling `names()` on a single _element_ of a list rather than the enitre list itself.

Comment: Yes, silly example of course, but i was trying to illustrate that `names` may not be appropriate.  If a single element,, such as `mtcars$wt`, is passed, how do you extract the `"wt"`

Comment: Give an example of why you would want to do this.  I am confident we won't need to pull the name off an individual list element.

Comment: Feel like im taking advantage of the OP's question :) but... I quite often do something similar to due to functions that i have to output tables. This is what i do: I normally have assigned `label`s. ..  `Hmisc::label(mtcars$wt) <- "Weight" ;  f <- function(X) list(Hmisc::label(X), mean(X)); f(mtcars$wt)`. It would be good to just extract the name rather than assigning labels

Comment: Agreed.  And right now I don't see a way to use an `apply` function on a data frame (or list) and also extract out the name of each column (element).  Which tells me that this use case isn't a big ask from most R users or else they would have included it.